# Google Maps Polygon to WKT

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, well-known-text

I need to convert a Google Maps polygon object (can has multi paths and holes) to wkt string (multipolygon) at client.  Then i'll able to save polygon as geography in Sql Server 2012.

I tried Wicket (https://github.com/arthur-e/Wicket) but it has a bug converting multipolygons.

Is there any ready to use library?
Any ideas, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code of the object or a sample object?

Answer (score 2):

I just enabled multipolygon support (Arrays of google.maps.Polygon instances) in Wicket, [version 1.0](https://github.com/arthur-e/Wicket). Clone the "master" branch or download the 1.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

If you can iterate the rings and holes you can do this yourself.  Format is pretty simple.  Pseudocode:

```
emit 'MULTIPOLYGON('

for each ring

  if it's not the first ring emit ','

  emit '(' 

  emit '('


    for each point in ring
     if it's not the first point emit ','

     emit X

     emit ' '

     emit Y

     end point loop
  emit ')'


  for each hole in ring

   emit ',('

     for each point in hole

      if it's not the first point emit ','

      emit X

      emit ' '

      emit Y

   end point loop

  emit ')'

  end hole loop

emit ')'

end ring loop

emit ')'
```

Comment: I'm curious why the thumbs down.  I don't believe there is any error, is there a disliking for pseudocode in general in this forum?

Comment: thanks for the answer, but there is no way to get rings and it's inner rings from google maps polygon object. it contains all paths but no containment information.

Comment: -1 because the pseudo-code cannot be applied with google map api

Comment: Ah.  Bummer.  Appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Actually, it supports GetPaths and from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494474/google-maps-api-polygon-with-hole-in-center it appears that direction of rotation determines holes.  However, by the time you have to compute order of rotation the code is not so trivial.

Comment: A discussion of how to determine direction of rotation is deep down on this page http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/ and it's really not so bad, just the sign of the cross product of adjacent edges.  Paul Bourke has some great resources if you need to implement your own geometric operations.  However, I know that's probably beyond the scope of this forum.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I guess it is something inefficient just trying to determine which path is a hole and belongs to which polygon. Instead, i draw all multipolygons as an array of single polygons which can contain holes. This time, only first path is outer ring and rest of the paths are inner rings.